# It is possible to slow down the virtual pc machine in Win7 (by reduce CPU etc.)

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, virtual-pc

I am trying to get a slow machine with IE8 to test for some customers. It is possible to slow down the virtual pc machine provided by MS? I did only find how to reduce RAM but not CPU.

Comment: Perhaps a SuperUser migration?

Comment: I think superuser.com is a better place to ask this. In enterprise VMs, it is possible to set CPU quotas, and if I remember correctly, VMWare Workstation was going to have that feature a few releases (and years) ago, but I don't know they did it or not...

Comment: Check out [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/265322/limiting-cpu-speed-in-a-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 0):

In options, you can choose to divide CPU time equally among all VPC instances, versus runing the active VPC at maximum speed.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible [due to the way virtual machines work](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2007/05/14/slowing-down-virtual-machines.aspx). As the virtual machines runs directly on the processor, you cannot slow that down. Your only option is to run on a virtual machine that does processor emulation.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox from Oracle does what you want. In the main interface, click Settings > System > Processor and set the Execution Cap to (say) 50%. Works nicely, except that the entire VM slows down (not just a specific application like IE).